# Why ComposeUIViewController callback is called twice in Compose Multiplatform?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, compose-multiplatform

I created a Compose Multiplatform project form [Compose Multiplatform Wizard](https://terrakok.github.io/Compose-Multiplatform-Wizard/). When i ran it on ios simulator it called the `ComposeUIViewController` callback twice, though `MainViewController` called only once.

I've following code in my `composeApp/src/iosMain/kotlin/main.kt`

```
fun MainViewController(systemAppearance: (isLight: Boolean) -> Unit): UIViewController {
    println("Outside ComposeUIViewController")

    return ComposeUIViewController {
        println("Inside ComposeUIViewController")
        App() }
}
```

below is the output.

[image]

Comment: I think this is an issue for https://github.com/terrakok/Compose-Multiplatform-Wizard repo

Comment: @gavr This issues was with compose and has been resolved. ref: https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-multiplatform/issues/3778